# Run a JS script on page load

Tags: javascript

I have a .js file that is the javascript translation of a java file.jar. I would like to run the file as soon as the HTML page is loaded. Is it possible? 
now the file is run using the following code

```
 <div class="w3-twothird" align="center">
       <script>
           cheerpjInit();
           cheerpjCreateDisplay(500,400);
           cheerpjRunJar("/app/tesi/homepage/disgrafia.jar");
       </script>
       </div>
```

I'd like to use only the js file and not the jar.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to run a piece of code once a site has loaded is using jQuery's `ready()` function.
Goes something like this

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
//Do the whatever you need to here
    });
```

Do keep in mind, however, that you will need jQuery on your page. Simplest way to get it is using CDN. Just paste this in your `<head> </head>`

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to use JQ, you can use an event listener for when the page loads, like so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Code to be executed when the DOM is ready
});
```

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-equivalent-of-document-ready-in-javascript/)

Cheers, hope it helps <3